# Python: Converting Torch tensor to bytes and saving as a wav file

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, tensor, torch

I have an audio file data into torch.tensor format. I want to convert it to bytes, and then need to save the file in ".wav" format. (I don't want to save the file directly from tensor to ".wav")

I use the following approach to convert the tensor into bytes, and then save it as wav.

```
audio_data_bytes = io.BytesIO()
torch.save(audio_data, audio_data_bytes)
audio_data_bytes.seek(0) 
res=audio_data_bytes.read()
open("abc.wav", 'wb').write(res)
```

Seems, it saves the wav file correctly, but when I check its property using soxi, I'm facing the following issue
`` soxi FAIL formats: can't open input file `abc.wav': WAVE: RIFF header not found ``

Would like to know, how can I fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`torch.save` pickles the file, which is a Python-exclusive format.
Use `torchaudio.save` instead.

[image]